# Surjective polynomial map of algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have seen a few questions similar to this on here but nothing the same as this I don't think, so I'm wondering if it's possible:

Given a surjective polynomial map of algebraic sets $\phi: X \to Y$, is the corresponding $k$-algebra homomorphism $\phi^*: k[X]\to k[Y]$ injective?

Like I said, I have seen a few similar questions asking about surjectivity of $\phi^*$ implying injectivity of $\phi$ but I haven't seen this way round. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: You appear to have made a typo in your definition of $\phi^*$. This map should go from $k[Y]$ to $k[X]$.

Comment: Is $k$ assumed to be algebraically closed?

Comment: The surjectivity of $\phi^{*}:\mathbb{K}[Y]\to\mathbb{K}[X]$ implies that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114532/let-f-u-rightarrow-w-be-a-morphism-of-affine-algebraic-sets-and-f-kw-r).